# Check javascript function is defined from java applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet, undefined, japplet

I am developing a Java applet where I call a javascript function:

```
boolean isAllowed = (boolean) win.eval("isPointMarkCreationAllowed()");
```

and I would like to **check if that function exists**, like we do in javascript:

```
if (isPointMarkCreationAllowed == 'function')
```

is there anyway to do that in Java?

Comment: `win.eval("isPointMarkCreationAllowed()");`  What happens when you call that and the function does *not* exist?  I would expect a `JSException` according to the JavaDocs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without actually having tried it, wouldn't

`win.eval("typeof isPointMarkCreationAllowed == 'function'");`

do exactly what you want and return a Boolean (true or false)?

Comment: I suspect it would would the trick.  If not, abstract out that code into a JS function that accepts the name of a function and returns true or false on evaluation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use reflection to test if a method exists.

For example if you have an object foo, you can get all the methods declared in the class of that object in the following:

```
Method[] methods = foo.getClass().getMethods();
```

This returns an array of the methods declared in the class.

Then just use a for loop to check if a specific method exists in the array returned

```
for (Method m : methods)
{
     if (m.getName().equals(someString))
     {
        //do something
     }
}
```

someString is the name of the method you're looking for, which is "isPointMarkCreationAllowed" in your case.

Use the following site to learn about reflections in Java
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodType.html

Comment: No, you can't use reflection to access or check JavaScript function from an applet.